# Solving equation involving max-row-sum matrix norm?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve for $\|A(a)\|_\infty=1$ where $A$ is a positive definite matrix parameterized by scalar $a$ and $\|.\|_\infty$ is max-row-sum norm of the matrix.

For the problem below, I know the answer is $2/7$ which can be obtained using `NMaximize`, meanwhile `Reduce` and `Solve` fail to simplify into 2/7. It looks like `Max` causes a problem for these functions.

Any tips how to make equations in terms of max-row-sum norm palatable to Mathematica?

```
mat = {{1 - 2 a + 3 a^2, 2 a^2}, {2 a^2, 1 - 4 a + 12 a^2}};
maxrowsum[mat_] := Max[Total[Abs[#]] & /@ mat];
(a /. Last[
   NMaximize[{maxrowsum[mat], maxrowsum[mat] <= 1}, 
    a]])  (*works*)
Assuming[{a > 0}, Solve[maxrowsum[mat] == 1, a]] (* fails *)
```

Comment: Note `maxrowsum[mat]` is the same as `Norm[mat, 1]`, though that does not help the main problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the domain `Reals` allows `Solve` to work:

```
Solve[maxrowsum[mat] == 1, a, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 0}, {a -> 2/7}}
> ```

Comment: Aha, that's the trick I needed! Turning it into linear programming is nice, but way too much work when I just need an answer fast :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set it up almost like a LP problem.

```
mat = {{1 - 2 a + 3 a^2, 2 a^2}, {2 a^2, 1 - 4 a + 12 a^2}};
dims = Dimensions[mat];
vars = Array[x, dims];
c1 = Flatten[
   Table[{vars[[i, j]] >= mat[[i, j]], 
     vars[[i, j]] >= -mat[[i, j]]}, {i, dims[[1]]}, {j, dims[[2]]}]];
c2 = Table[Total[vars[[i]]] <= 1, {i, dims[[1]]}];
c3 = Append[Thread[max >= Total[Transpose[vars]]], max <= 1];

constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3]
allvars = Flatten[{vars, max}]
```

In[563]:= constraints = Join[c1, c2, c3]

```
allvars = Flatten[{vars, max}]

(* Out[563]= {x[1, 1] >= 1 - 2 a + 3 a^2, x[1, 1] >= -1 + 2 a - 3 a^2, 
 x[1, 2] >= 2 a^2, x[1, 2] >= -2 a^2, x[2, 1] >= 2 a^2, 
 x[2, 1] >= -2 a^2, x[2, 2] >= 1 - 4 a + 12 a^2, 
 x[2, 2] >= -1 + 4 a - 12 a^2, x[1, 1] + x[1, 2] <= 1, 
 x[2, 1] + x[2, 2] <= 1, max >= x[1, 1] + x[1, 2], 
 max >= x[2, 1] + x[2, 2], max <= 1}

Out[564]= {x[1, 1], x[1, 2], x[2, 1], x[2, 2], max} *)
```

Now use `Maximize`.

```
Maximize[{a, constraints}, Join[allvars, {a}]]

(* Out[554]= {2/7, {x[1, 1] -> 3/4, x[1, 2] -> 13/64, x[2, 1] -> 8/49, 
  x[2, 2] -> 41/49, max -> 1, a -> 2/7}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively set it up as a univariate minimization and use calculus to solve exactly. We use the usual `sqrt(x^2)` to form `abs(x)` and insist that the product of squared differences of rownorms from 1 be zero. Since this is a product of squares we use calculus to find candidate minima.

```
mat = {{1 - 2 a + 3 a^2, 2 a^2}, {2 a^2, 1 - 4 a + 12 a^2}};
rownorms = Total[Sqrt[Transpose[mat]^2]];
obj = Apply[Times, (rownorms - 1)^2]
expr = Together[PowerExpand[Together[D[obj, a]], Assumptions -> a > 0]]

(* Out[666]= (-1 + 2 Sqrt[a^4] + Sqrt[(1 - 2 a + 3 a^2)^2])^2 (-1 + 
   2 Sqrt[a^4] + Sqrt[(1 - 4 a + 12 a^2)^2])^2

Out[667]= 32 (8 a^3 - 120 a^4 + 642 a^5 - 1470 a^6 + 1225 a^7) *)
```

Find candidate solutions.

```
candidates = Union[Flatten[Solve[expr == 0, a]]]

(* Out[668]= {a -> 0, a -> 2/7, a -> 2/5, a -> 1/35 (9 - Sqrt[11]), 
 a -> 1/35 (9 + Sqrt[11])} *)
```

Select any that actually do make the objective minimal (zero) and moreover give a max rownorm of 1.

```
Select[candidates, ((obj /. #) == 0) && (Max[rownorms /. #] <= 1) &]

(* Out[669]= {a -> 0, a -> 2/7} *)
```